# NodeJS + jQuery: Redirect after POST: client or server - which is better?

Tags: jquery, node.js, redirect, post

I'm trying to redirect to a specified page after post via jQuery. Here's my POST code:

```
$.post("/addcompany", {
name: $('#company_name').val(),
phone: $('#company_phone').val(),
email: $('#company_email').val(),
suppliers: JSON.stringify(suppliers),
}, function(){
    alert('after post'); 
    window.location.href = '/companies';
    }
);
```

This is my backend code on NodeJS:

```
app.post('/addcompany',function(req,res){
db.collection("companies",function(err,collection){
    collection.insert( {
        "name":req.body.name,
        "email":req.body.email,
        "phone":req.body.phone,
        "suppliers" : JSON.parse(req.body.suppliers)
    });
});
res.redirect('/companies');
});
```

The problem is if I don'r redirect to '/companies' both in jQuery script and in NodeJS-backend code, my redirection doesn't work. Where should I place my redirection code? Is it normal, that I have to place it twice - both on server and on client? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only redirect in this situation on the frontend. To achieve that properly I think you should have `res.send()` on the backend (empty 200 response, to let the client know everything went ok on the server side).

If you want to redirect on the server side than you shouldn't use Ajax, just plain old post request.

Comment: Thanks, it works! As I understand, res.send() is a necessary condition  to make AJAX-code execute callback-function?

Comment: It's not about that function, but I suppose it's about the response code. `res.send()` returns 200 (unless specified custom code), while `res.redirect()` returns 301 as a response code and my guess is that jQuery doesn't like anything other than 2xx (but that should be checked).

Answer (score 3):

Sending a redirect code in response to an AJAX request won't automatically make the browser do anything; your client-side response handler would have to look at the result code and do the redirect itself if it saw one. I'd actually recommend doing that rather than automatically changing `window.location.href` to a fixed URL in your client-side code, simply because your server-side code might eventually need to respond differently under error conditions (Not A Good Idea for client-side code to blithely assume that everything went right with a request to the server).